# Why does * only return the first XML tag when used with an XPath node function?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the local names of ***all*** items inside document:

```
<document>
  <item_0001>Erstes Element</item_0001>
  <item_0002>Zweites Element</item_0002>
  <item_0003>Drittes Element</item_0003>
  <item_0004>Viertes Element</item_0004>
  <other_0001>Erstes Element</other_0001>
  <other_0002>Zweites Element</other_0002>
</document>
```

The following only returns the tag name of the ***first*** item:

```
local-name(/document/*)
```

Shouldn't `*` make it return ***all*** items?  Why doesn't it, and how do I return all tag names like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression,

```
/document/*
```

does return all items.  It's **XPath 1.0's** automatic conversion of the resulting node-set to the first node ahead of the call to `local-name()` that's causing your confusion.  (If you were using XPath 2.0, `local-name(/document/*)` would have resulted in a runtime error.)

There is no good XPath-only solution to achieve your results in **XPath 1.0**.  Typically you'd apply a function to the resulting node-set via the hosting language (XSLT, Python, Java, etc).

In **XPath 2.0**, you can use

```
/document/*/local-name()
```

(or just `/document/*/name()` as there are no namespaces in play anyway) to achieve your result:

```
item_0001
item_0002
item_0003
item_0004
other_0001
other_0002
```